# Troubles Drawing a Vertex Array

Tags: c++, opengl

I've got a bit of a problem getting getting this working. The goal is to draw an Icosahedron. Ill eventually be subdividing it to get a sphere, but right now im puzzled as to why it isnt being drawn. I'm quite new to both OpenGL and C++ but have been working with Java for 2 years (...though first year uni hardly counts where I am :P)

The Icosahedron code is based off. http://www.gamedev.net/topic/623118-icosphere-generation-code-not-working-properlyhelp/

```
IcoSphereCreator icoGen;
    MeshGeometry3D ico;
    ico.Vertexs = vertexs;
    ico.TriangleIndices = indices;
    ico.GenerateVertexArray();
```

This generates an array of Point3Ds. I then copy this into an array which I use as the vertex array (yeah this is pretty messy :/).

```
static GLfloat vertArray[60];
for(int i = 0;i < ico.VertexArraySize;i = i+3){
    vertArray[i] = ico.VertexArray[i].x;
    vertArray[i+1] = ico.VertexArray[i].y;
    vertArray[i+2] = ico.VertexArray[i].z;
}

for(int i = 0;i < sizeof(vertArray)/sizeof(vertArray[0]);i++){
    std::cout << vertArray[i];
    std::cout << "  l   ";
}
```

The output verifies that the vertex array has 60 correct elements.

Here I create the buffers.

```
GLuint vertexbufferico;
glGenBuffers(1, &vertexbufferico);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbufferico);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertArray), vertArray, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

GLuint normalbufferico;
glGenBuffers(1, &normalbufferico);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, normalbufferico);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertArray), vertArray, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

Here is where I pass the attributes into the shader code.

```
        // 1rst attribute buffer : vertices
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbufferico);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0,3,GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE,0, (void*)0);//Attrib,size,type,normalised,stride,offset

    /// 3rd attribute buffer : normals
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, normalbufferico);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1,3,GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE,0,(void*)0);//Attrib,size,type,normalised,stride,offset

    // Draw the Icosaherdon !
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 60);
```

Currently the output is nothing - just an empty window.

What appears to be the same process (in my head) is correctly drawing a cube from arrays of vertexs, uv coordinates and normals.

I've been at this for a few days now and am getting to the stage where I think im just not seeing something that pretty simple.

Here is the full code. Its really hacked together - after I get this functionality sorted ill be comfortable with spending time to improve structure etc. The program is based off what I've learned from http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/.

```
int main( void )
{
    // Initialise GLFW
    if( !glfwInit() )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "Failed to initialize GLFW\n" );
        return -1;
    }

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_SAMPLES, 4);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

    // Open a window and create its OpenGL context
    window = glfwCreateWindow( 1024, 768, "Tutorial 04 - Colored Cube", NULL, NULL);
    if( window == NULL ){
        fprintf( stderr, "Failed to open GLFW window. If you have an Intel GPU, they are not 3.3 compatible. Try the 2.1 version of the tutorials.\n" );
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    // Initialize GLEW
    glewExperimental = true; // Needed for core profile
    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to initialize GLEW\n");
        return -1;
    }

    // Ensure we can capture the escape key being pressed below
    glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_STICKY_KEYS, GL_TRUE);

    // Dark blue background
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.4f, 0.0f);

    // Enable depth test
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    // Accept fragment if it closer to the camera than the former one
    glDepthFunc(GL_LESS); 

    GLuint VertexArrayID;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VertexArrayID);
    glBindVertexArray(VertexArrayID);

        // Create and compile our GLSL program from the shaders
    GLuint programCube = LoadShaders( "cube.vertexshader", "cube.fragmentshader" );
    GLuint programSphere = LoadShaders( "sphere.vertexshader", "sphere.fragmentshader" );

    // Get a handle for our "MVP" uniform
    GLuint MatrixIDCube = glGetUniformLocation(programCube, "MVP");
    GLuint ViewMatrixIDCube = glGetUniformLocation(programCube, "V");
    GLuint ModelMatrixIDCube = glGetUniformLocation(programCube, "M");

    GLuint MatrixIDSphere = glGetUniformLocation(programSphere, "MVP");
    GLuint ViewMatrixIDSphere = glGetUniformLocation(programSphere, "V");
    GLuint ModelMatrixIDSphere = glGetUniformLocation(programSphere, "M");

    // Load the texture using any two methods
    //GLuint Texture = loadBMP_custom("uvtemplate.bmp");
    GLuint Texture = loadDDS("img3.DDS");

    // Get a handle for our "myTextureSampler" uniform
    GLuint TextureID  = glGetUniformLocation(programCube, "myTextureSampler");

    // Our vertices. Tree consecutive floats give a 3D vertex; Three consecutive vertices give a triangle.
    // A cube has 6 faces with 2 triangles each, so this makes 6*2=12 triangles, and 12*3 vertices
    static const GLfloat g_vertex_buffer_data[] = { 
        -1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,
        -1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f,
        -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
         1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f,
        -1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,
        -1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f,
         1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f,
        -1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,
         1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,
         1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f,
         1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,
        -1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,
        -1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,
        -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
        -1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f,
         1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f,
        -1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f,
        -1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,
        -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
        -1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f,
         1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f,
         1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
         1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,
         1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f,
         1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,
         1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
         1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f,
         1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
         1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f,
        -1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f,
         1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
        -1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f,
        -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
         1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
        -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
         1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f
    };

    // Two UV coordinatesfor each vertex. They were created withe Blender.
    static const GLfloat g_uv_buffer_data[] = { 
    0.000059f, 1.0f-0.000004f,
    0.000103f, 1.0f-0.336048f,
    0.335973f, 1.0f-0.335903f,
    1.000023f, 1.0f-0.000013f,
    0.667979f, 1.0f-0.335851f,
    0.999958f, 1.0f-0.336064f,

    0.667979f, 1.0f-0.335851f,
    0.336024f, 1.0f-0.671877f,
    0.667969f, 1.0f-0.671889f,
    1.000023f, 1.0f-0.000013f,
    0.668104f, 1.0f-0.000013f,
    0.667979f, 1.0f-0.335851f,

    0.000059f, 1.0f-0.000004f,
    0.335973f, 1.0f-0.335903f,
    0.336098f, 1.0f-0.000071f,
    0.667979f, 1.0f-0.335851f,
    0.335973f, 1.0f-0.335903f,
    0.336024f, 1.0f-0.671877f,

    1.000004f, 1.0f-0.671847f,
    0.999958f, 1.0f-0.336064f,
    0.667979f, 1.0f-0.335851f,
    0.668104f, 1.0f-0.000013f,
    0.335973f, 1.0f-0.335903f,
    0.667979f, 1.0f-0.335851f,

    0.335973f, 1.0f-0.335903f,
    0.668104f, 1.0f-0.000013f,
    0.336098f, 1.0f-0.000071f,
    0.000103f, 1.0f-0.336048f,
    0.000004f, 1.0f-0.671870f,
    0.336024f, 1.0f-0.671877f,

    0.000103f, 1.0f-0.336048f,
    0.336024f, 1.0f-0.671877f,
    0.335973f, 1.0f-0.335903f,
    0.667969f, 1.0f-0.671889f,
    1.000004f, 1.0f-0.671847f,
    0.667979f, 1.0f-0.335851f
    };

        static const GLfloat g_normal_buffer_data[] = {
        -1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,
        -1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f,
        -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
         1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f,
        -1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,
        -1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f,
         1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f,
        -1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,
         1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,
         1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f,
         1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,
        -1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,
        -1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,
        -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
        -1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f,
         1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f,
        -1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f,
        -1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,
        -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
        -1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f,
         1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f,
         1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
         1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,
         1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f,
         1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,
         1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
         1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f,
         1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
         1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f,
        -1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f,
         1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
        -1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f,
        -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
         1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
        -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
        1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f};

        #define X .525731112119133606 
        #define Z .850650808352039932

        Point3D vdata[] = {(-X, 0.0, Z),(X, 0.0, Z),(-X, 0.0, -Z),(X, 0.0, -Z),(0.0, Z, X),(0.0, Z, -X)
            ,(0.0, -Z, X),(0.0, -Z, -X),(Z, X, 0.0),(-Z, X, 0.0),(Z, -X, 0.0),(-Z, -X, 0.0)};

        std::vector<Point3D> vertexs (vdata, vdata + sizeof(vdata) / sizeof(vdata[0]) );
        vertexs.assign(vdata,vdata+sizeof(vdata) / sizeof(vdata[0]));

        static int tindices[]={1,4,0,     4,9,0,    4,5,9,    8,5,4,    1,8,4,
         1,10,8,    10,3,8,   8,3,5,    3,2,5,    3,7,2,
         3,10,7,    10,6,7,   6,11,7,   6,0,11,   6,1,0,
         10,1,6,    11,0,9,   2,11,9,   5,2,9,    11,2,7};

        std::vector<int> indices (tindices, tindices + sizeof(tindices) / sizeof(tindices[0]) );
        indices.assign(tindices,tindices+sizeof(tindices) / sizeof(tindices[0]));

        //static GLfloat icoVert[(sizeof(tindices)/sizeof(tindices[0]))*3];
        //  for (int i=0; i<sizeof(tindices)/sizeof(tindices[0]); ++i) {
        //  icoVert[(3*i)+0] = vdata[tindices[i]][0];
        //  icoVert[(3*i)+1] = vdata[tindices[i]][1];
        //  icoVert[(3*i)+2] = vdata[tindices[i]][2];
        //} 
        //
        //  static GLfloat icoNorm[(sizeof(tindices)/sizeof(tindices[0]))*3];
        //  for (int i=0; i<sizeof(tindices)/sizeof(tindices[0]); ++i) {
        //  icoVert[(3*i)+0] = vdata[tindices[i]][0];
        //  icoVert[(3*i)+1] = vdata[tindices[i]][1];
        //  icoVert[(3*i)+2] = vdata[tindices[i]][2];
        //} 
    IcoSphereCreator icoGen;
    MeshGeometry3D ico;
    ico.Vertexs = vertexs;
    ico.TriangleIndices = indices;
    ico.GenerateVertexArray();

    static GLfloat vertArray[60];
    for(int i = 0;i < ico.VertexArraySize;i = i+3){
        vertArray[i] = ico.VertexArray[i].x;
        vertArray[i+1] = ico.VertexArray[i].y;
        vertArray[i+2] = ico.VertexArray[i].z;
    }

    for(int i = 0;i < sizeof(vertArray)/sizeof(vertArray[0]);i++){
        std::cout << vertArray[i];
        std::cout << "  l   ";
    }

    GLuint vertexbuffer;
    glGenBuffers(1, &vertexbuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(g_vertex_buffer_data), g_vertex_buffer_data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    GLuint uvbuffer;
    glGenBuffers(1, &uvbuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, uvbuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(g_uv_buffer_data), g_uv_buffer_data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    GLuint normalbuffer;
    glGenBuffers(1, &normalbuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, normalbuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(g_normal_buffer_data), g_normal_buffer_data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    GLuint vertexbufferico;
    glGenBuffers(1, &vertexbufferico);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbufferico);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertArray), vertArray, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    GLuint normalbufferico;
    glGenBuffers(1, &normalbufferico);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, normalbufferico);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertArray), vertArray, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    // Get a handle for our "LightPosition" uniform
    glUseProgram(programCube);
    glUseProgram(programSphere);
    GLuint LightIDCube = glGetUniformLocation(programCube, "LightPosition_worldspace");
    GLuint LightIDSphere = glGetUniformLocation(programSphere, "LightPosition_worldspace");
    std::cout << "drawing";

    do{

        // Clear the screen
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        // Use our shader
        glUseProgram(programCube);
        // Compute the MVP matrix from keyboard and mouse input
        computeMatricesFromInputs();
        vec3 gPosition1(-1.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        vec3 gPosition2( 1.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

        glm::mat4 ProjectionMatrix = getProjectionMatrix();
        glm::mat4 ViewMatrix = getViewMatrix();
        glm::mat4 TranslationMatrixSqu = translate(mat4(), gPosition1);
        glm::mat4 TranslationMatrixIco = translate(mat4(), gPosition2);
        glm::mat4 ModelMatrixSqu = glm::mat4(1.0)*TranslationMatrixSqu;
        glm::mat4 ModelMatrixIco = glm::mat4(1.0)*TranslationMatrixIco;

        glm::mat4 MVP1 = ProjectionMatrix * ViewMatrix * ModelMatrixSqu;
        glm::mat4 MVP2 = ProjectionMatrix * ViewMatrix * ModelMatrixIco;



        // Bind our texture in Texture Unit 0
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, Texture);
        // Set our "myTextureSampler" sampler to user Texture Unit 0
        glUniform1i(TextureID, 0);

        // Send our transformation to the currently bound shader, 
        // in the "MVP" uniform
        glUniformMatrix4fv(MatrixIDSphere, 1, GL_FALSE, &MVP2[0][0]);
        glUniformMatrix4fv(ModelMatrixIDSphere, 1, GL_FALSE, &ModelMatrixIco[0][0]);
        glUniformMatrix4fv(ViewMatrixIDSphere, 1, GL_FALSE, &ViewMatrix[0][0]);
        glm::vec3 lightPos = glm::vec3(4,4,4);
        glUniform3f(LightIDSphere, lightPos.x, lightPos.y, lightPos.z);

        // 1rst attribute buffer : vertices
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbufferico);
        glVertexAttribPointer(0,3,GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE,0, (void*)0);//Attrib,size,type,normalised,stride,offset

        /// 3rd attribute buffer : normals
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, normalbufferico);
        glVertexAttribPointer(1,3,GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE,0,(void*)0);//Attrib,size,type,normalised,stride,offset

        // Draw the Icosaherdon !
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 60); 


        // 1rst attribute buffer : vertices
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer);
        glVertexAttribPointer(0,3,GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE,0,(void*)0); //Attrib,size,type,normalised,stride,offset

        // 2nd attribute buffer : UVs
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, uvbuffer);
        glVertexAttribPointer(1,2, GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE,0,(void*)0);  //Attrib,size,type,normalised,stride,offset

        // 3rd attribute buffer : normals
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, normalbuffer);
        glVertexAttribPointer(2,3,GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE,0, (void*)0);  //Attrib,size,type,normalised,stride,offset

        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36);
        glDeleteTextures(1, &TextureID);



        glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);
        glDisableVertexAttribArray(2);

        // Swap buffers
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();

    } // Check if the ESC key was pressed or the window was closed
    while( glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE ) != GLFW_PRESS &&
           glfwWindowShouldClose(window) == 0 );

    // Cleanup VBO and shader
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &vertexbuffer);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &uvbuffer);
    glDeleteTextures(1, &TextureID);
    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &VertexArrayID);
        glDeleteProgram(programCube);
                glDeleteProgram(programSphere);



    // Close OpenGL window and terminate GLFW
    glfwTerminate();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why `60` in `glDrawArrays`? It expects indices count; your array of 60 floats defines only 20 points (3 floats per point). And 20 points doesn't really round up to triangles, why is that? Also check for `glGetError`, or even better - use [KHR_debug](https://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/KHR/debug.txt)